# How would you design this relational database?

Tags: mysql

I've been given lot's of ideas that I had no idea how they would translate into real life, I've just designed my first one to many table schema so please bear with me :)

I have an **events** table that contains information such as *music genres*. What I did is that I created a separate table called **music_styles**. Each row in **music_styles** contains an ID and a name for that genre. Until now, I took that ID and put inserted that into a foreign key column in the **events** table, which works if each event were to have only one musical genre. So what I wanted was a solution for multiple genres and I was told the way to go was to create a third table that would reference both an event id and a music_style id. How would that work? I have no idea how to start so any thoughts are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a third table, we can call it events_music_styles with two columns: event_id and music_style_id; event_id will obviously contain the id of an event and music_style_id the id of a genre. 
This way you can have for example two or more rows with the same event associated to different genres. You should also remove the information about music genres in the events table. 

This is the standard way of doing this. You should study a little bit of database design and normalization, there are important but easy concept to learn that will really help you.

Comment: Thank you Simone :), I will take your advice! What I don't understand, however is where I will reference that in the end result table? When I have a "Music Styles" column, the user will see "Latino, Reggae". But what will be in the back process of the column? Will that be a column from the events table which will contain the ID of the 'music_style_id' table or what?

Comment: Yes, you have to have a column music_style_id also in the music_style table :)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I confused it with the events_music_styles. What I'm trying to say is, that everyone that contributed - said that events_music_styles has only TWO columns. One for the ID of the event, and one for the ID of the music style, which means that it has no ID for itself? How would I then go about referencing a row in the events table?

Comment: The events table also should have a column event_id; one important tip in database design is to always add a numeric identifier to each table to use it in cases like this; so you will have a events_id in the events table and a music_style_id in the music_style table; you then will use this ids to establish the association.

Comment: No! you don't need the events_music_style_has_music style and the events_music_style_has_events! you only need the events_music_style table directly connected to the events and music_style tables!

Comment: Actually, that's just the way the application builds the arrows, but they are both pointed to the ID's of those tables. I'm ashamed to ask you this, but when I do a query, will I have to do an inner join of the events_music_styles? I'm sure that when I'll do a query for an event with two musical styles, that two rows will still be returned

Comment: you will need a join of the three tables...and yes you will have different rows for different musical styles associated to the same event

Comment: Cool, so then that's where GROUP_CONCAT comes in to take all those rows and put it into one?

Comment: Thank you Simone, so the next step for me is Google search! :)

Answer (score 1):

pufAmuf,

You'd create a third table, say `event_styles`, with only two columns: `event_id` and `music_style_id`.  If an event referenced only one style, you'd add one row to the `event_styles` table with the appropriate `event_id` and `music_style_id`.  If an event referenced several styles, you'd add a row for each style.  Each of those rows would contain the same `event_id` and the appropriate `music_style_id`.

For example, suppose event 01 references pop, and event 02 references jazz and rock:

```
|events                 |  | music_styles |  | event_styles               |
|-----------------------|  |--------------|  |----------------------------|
| id | data             |  | id | style   |  | event_id | music_style_ id |
|----+------------------|  |----+---------|  |----------+-----------------|
| 01 | "event info"     |  | 01 | jazz    |  | 01       | 03              |
| 02 | "2nd event info" |  | 02 | rock    |  | 02       | 01              |
-------------------------  | 03 | pop     |  | 02       | 02              |
                           ----------------  ------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! I think I understand what you're saying with the tables - so what is the next step in showing the users all the music styles in one column? Since the query will show the events table, will the events table have a foreign key column that will take data from the event_styles table or will that table be just somehow joined up with my events table? Thanks again Adam! :)

Comment: Thanks for the expansion of your explanation Adam :). So then what joins the content of the two rows for one event in 'event_styles' into one column what results in a string 'Jazz, Rock' ?

Comment: Once you have an `event` (and therefore its `id`), you can find the associated `music_styles` with `SELECT music_style_id FROM event_styles WHERE event_id = YOUR_EVENT_ID`.  Then you can use the `music_style_id`s to query the `music_styles` table.  You can probably combine those steps into a single query, but it's easier to understand this way.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your main table is Events and each event will have one entry with and id (maybe a GUID to make life easy). You will have a second table which will then have one or multiple rows which will have the music styles for the event. The music styles will be referenced off of the third table (which you already have) for genres.

A good design will have any item be it event or genres only in one place and referenced as many times as you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called a many-to-many relationship or lookup. It works because any combination of entities from either table can be explicily linked together through the third table.

For example:

```
Table 1 - music styles
1 Techno
2 Breaks

Table 2 - music event
1 Blagfest
2 Rockers Night
```

Let's say that the Blagfest event has techno and breaks and that Rockers Night has just breaks. The third table would contain the following pairings:

```
Event Style
1     1      - Blagfest has Techno
1     2      - Blagfest has Breaks
2     2      - Rockers night has Breaks
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you said is correct, **EventID** and **StyleID** in **TBL_EVENT_MUSIC_STYLE** will point to **EventID** and **StyleID** of **TBL_EVENT** and **TBL_MUSIC_STYLE** respectively.

```
TBL_EVENT(EventID,Column1,Column2)
TBL_MUSIC_STYLE(StyleID,Column4,Column5)
TBL_EVENT_MUSIC_STYLE(EventID, StyleID)
```

generally you don’t use plural names for table names. So it’s better if you can have table names as **music_style** etc rather than **music _styles**

Sriwantha Sri Aravinda

Comment: Hi Sriwantha, would you think this is okay to do http://i.imgur.com/Oea98.jpg :) ?